# Extract numbers, dot and comma using regex match

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to extract amount `$50,000.00` from string which has number, comma and dot. My code is below:

```
var amount = '$50,000.00Fund Transfer to XXXX9090 Ref #0675'.match(/[^0-9,.]/);
```

Comment: The `^` at the start of a character class means "not", which isn't the behaviour you're describing. Also you only match a single character.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `[\d,]+\.\d+` in case dot is required in the number, like: `[\d,]+\.\d+`.

In case dot is optional - you may use `[\d,]+(\.\d+)?`,

but in this case you may capture undesired values like: `9090` and `0675`.

As result your code must looks like this:

```
var amount = '50,000.00Fund Transfer to XXXX9090 Ref #0675'.match(/[\d,]+\.\d+/)[0]
```

In case this number must be the most left number - like this:

```
var amount = '50,000.00Fund Transfer to XXXX9090 Ref #0675'.match(/^[\d,]+\.\d+/)[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

`^` at a start of a charactor class means `not`. And also you are missing `+`.
Meaning of your expression is `not a digit or , or . and only once`

Answer is 
`/^[\d,\.]+/` or `/^[0-9,\.]+/`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one - `\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*\.\d{2}`. It should match only those numbers which are properly formatted with decimal separator (dot `.`) and thousands separator (comma `,`):

```js
const amount = '50,000.00Fund Transfer to XXXX9090 Ref #0675'.match(/\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*\.\d{2}/)[0];

console.log(amount)
```

You can also match numbers with a dollar sign at the beginning, but you need to escape that character in your regexp, since it has a special meaning (end of string):

`\$\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*\.\d{2}`

Answer (score 0):

Match if the string starts with one, two or three digits, followed by any amount of sets that include exactly a comma and three digits.

```
^[0-9]{1,3}((\,[0-9]{3})|)+
```

Additionally, you could add the following term to optionally allow for exactly two decimals:

```
^[0-9]{1,3}((\,[0-9]{3})|)+((\.[0-9]{2})|)
```

In your case, the amount has a leading dollar sign, so we would have to alter our regex as follows:

```
^\$[0-9]{1,3}((\,[0-9]{3})|)+((\.[0-9]{2})|)
```